# HAProxy on Centos 7

Tags: linux, load-balancing, haproxy, web-administration

**This is the error I'm getting when I check the HAProxy status:**

[root@localhost haproxy]# systemctl status haproxy.service
● haproxy.service - HAProxy Load Balancer

Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/haproxy.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   **Active: failed (Result: exit-code)**

Process: 4947 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/haproxy-systemd-wrapper -f /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p /run/haproxy.pid $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 4947 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

**These are the steps I followed to configure HAProxy**

yum install haproxy
cd /etc/haproxy
mv haproxy.cfg haproxy.cfg.bak
created a haproxy.cfg file in /etc/haproxy/

systemctl restart haproxy.service
systemctl enable haproxy.service

Pointed browser to http://{IPADDRESS}/SubManagerWeb/#/main/home

Comment: `sudo systemctl ...`?

Answer (score 0):

Please share the config file that you created. This error is particularly not showing any related error so issue cannot be identified.